# Fovis_ros using freenect_launch has depth image format error

Tags: ros, kinect, fovis, freenect-launch, fovis-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm running ROS in indigo and use fovis_ros by freenect with a kinect xbox360. But there is  an error:

`Depth image must be in 32bit floating point format!`

I find a similar problem [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/206888/fovis_ros-depth-image-format-error/). But , he use openni and run ROS in Hydro. Here is the launch file.

```
<launch>
  <arg name="camera" default="camera" />

  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" args="manager" name="nodelet_manager" />
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="convert_openni_fovis" 
        args="load depth_image_proc/convert_metric nodelet_manager">
    <remap from="image_raw" to="$(arg camera)/depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw"/>
    <remap from="image" to="$(arg camera)/depth_registered/image_raw"/>
  </node>

  <node pkg="fovis_ros" type="fovis_mono_depth_odometer" name="kinect_odometer" >
    <remap from="/camera/rgb/image_rect" 
           to="$(arg camera)/rgb/image_rect_mono" />
    <remap from="/camera/rgb/camera_info" 
           to="$(arg camera)/rgb/camera_info" />
    <remap from="/camera/depth_registered/camera_info" 
           to="$(arg camera)/depth_registered/sw_registered/camera_info" />
    <remap from="/camera/depth_registered/image_rect" 
           to="$(arg camera)/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw" />
    <param name="approximate_sync" type="bool" value="True" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

I wonder if I use openni, I will solve this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213333/fovis_ros-using-freenect_launch-has-depth-image-format-error/) by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2015-07-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2015-07-13**:
Check the [example launchfile](https://github.com/srv/fovis/blob/indigo/fovis_ros/launch/fovis_hydro_openni.launch) in fovis_ros at github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I was indeed having your same problem and it was because of the launch file I was using, which was [this one](https://gist.github.com/Athria/1a723ce02a96908f13dc). I still don't know why it didn't work, but adding the oppeni_launch include to the example launch file that Miguel Massot linked above fixed my problem, I don't think it should be any different in your case because you use Indigo. My current, working, launch file is this one:

```
<launch>
   <include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch">
  </include>


  <arg name="camera" default="camera" />
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" args="manager" name="nodelet_manager" />
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="convert_openni_fovis" 
        args="load depth_image_proc/convert_metric nodelet_manager">
    <remap from="image_raw" to="$(arg camera)/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw"/>
    <remap from="image" to="$(arg camera)/depth_registered/image_rect"/>
  </node>

  <node pkg="fovis_ros" type="fovis_mono_depth_odometer" name="kinect_odometer" >
    <remap from="/camera/rgb/image_rect" to="$(arg camera)/rgb/image_rect_mono" />
    <remap from="/camera/rgb/camera_info" to="$(arg camera)/rgb/camera_info" />
    <remap from="/camera/depth_registered/camera_info" to="$(arg camera)/depth_registered/sw_registered/camera_info" />
    <remap from="/camera/depth_registered/image_rect" to="$(arg camera)/depth_registered/image_rect" />
    <param name="approximate_sync" type="bool" value="True" />
    <param name="publish_tf" type="bool" value="False" />
  </node>

</launch>
```

Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [Athria](https://answers.ros.org/users/20494/athria/) with karma: 78 on 2015-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-07-13**:
Thanks for your answer!
In fact, my computer can't identify kinect by openni, so I use freenect in these days.
As you say, I believe when I solve this problem( be identify by openni ) , I could also use this package.
Thanks again.

**Comment by [Athria](https://answers.ros.org/users/20494/athria/) on 2015-07-14**:
Too bad about openni, are you by any chance working from a virtual machine? I had a similar issue with one. I haven't used freenect, but if it publishes the required image and depth topics you might be able to use them by just changing the remaps and the upper include from the working launch file

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-07-14**:
You mean openni is not good? As far as I know, asus xtion pro can only be identified by openni. I wanna to buy xtion this summer. If I could get the right format, maybe there will be other problems. Well, my system is a 32bit one.

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-07-14**:
I use my colleague's computer ( Ubuntu14.04 ,64 bit, indigo) and test your launch file, but find some problems about TF.
I solve the problem by change the openni.launch and openni2_tf_prefix.launch.[here](https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_launch/tree/indigo-devel/launch)
Now,I can use it.

**Comment by [Athria](https://answers.ros.org/users/20494/athria/) on 2015-07-22**:
Sorry I could not answer before, I read about some problems with the openni_launch and the Kinect in Indigo, but in Hydro it works just fine with the simple launch file. I am glad you could make it work.

**Comment by [Athria](https://answers.ros.org/users/20494/athria/) on 2015-07-22**:
I looked a bit more into it. With a fresh install of both Fovis and the freenect_launch in Indigo (14.04.2) the Kinect works well, using the same launch file but with the respective